# In Google Analytics, how do I ignore a specific subdomain as a referral? The proper use of _addIgnoredRef

Tags: google-analytics, seo

I need help understanding and also instructions on how to properly use "_addIgnoredRef".

First I will explain what type of situation I am in.  We have 2 subdomains (each subdomain has it's own webserver/application) that is being used as one website, meaning there are links going back and forth between these two subdomains.  For the sake of just using an example, let's say we have "**abc.website.com**" and "**123.website.com**".  We have links on abc.website.com that links to 123.website.com and vice versa, however they are treated as one website.

Second, we do not develop or change any google anyalytics code to the domain **website.com**.  We only have access to the subdomains, **abc.website.com** and **123.website.com.**

So the issue we are seeing is that Google Analytics is telling us that we have referrals coming from these two subdomains.  I understand that it's because we have these two subdomains linking back and forth.

I do understand GA has a command that allows me to IGNORE the referrals by using **_addIgnoredRef** .  However, am I safe to assume that I go to abc.website.com and append this to the GA code,

```
    _gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', '123.website.com']);
```

and vice versa for 123.website.com?

Ultimately we want to not see referrals coming from 123.website.com and abc.website.com, but we don't mind seeing referrals coming from website.com or www.website.com.

If what I have assume is correct, then I must be missing something because that is what I have setup currently.  Then my next question would be, do I have this correct?

```
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'website.com']);
```

Do I need the trailing period?

You can go on and on about how that having two subdomains as one website isn't a good idea for many reasons but this is what was provided to us when we first started.  We will eventually merge them into one website, but for now let's just say it will take awhile and we need to "bandage the situation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, adding _addIgnoreRef will only convert the referral into direct traffic. If this is desired, then yes, you would add:

```
    _gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', '123.website.com']); //add to abc.website.com
```

and

```
    _gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', 'abc.website.com']); //add to 123.website.com
```

The trailing period isn't necessary, just as long as you are consistent across the entire website. According to Google, the trailing period comes more into play when you have multiple layers of subdomains - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory?csw=1#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setDomainName

Comment: You are a godsend.  Thank you for answering my stupid question.